# Particle system different than render

Tags: particles, physics, system

I am using cycles to render out a cold sparks clip for NYE. I have rendered out one clip and it will pass as usable but i want to make it look more realistic. So, I added about 25000 particles, I changed the normal velocity from 1 m/s to 10m/s and the trajectory looks amazing in viewport but when I go to render, it seems the velocity jumps around a bunch causing weird glitches resulting in a poopy looking clip. Does adding a ton of cube particles like I am doing cause the system to misbehave typically? The first clip I rendered had about 15000 particles and as amount of particles is the only thing I changed I'm guessing that is the issue but would really love to hear an insight someone might have on the topic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: First important question: have you baked the particle simulation before rendering?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thank you for the reply. I have tried baking but the particles do not show up. I was using two identical particle systems with one having a slight rotation on the z axis, I would bake  both of those but only one would show up in the render so i reverted to using just one system and one emitter but now I get a result that looks like I keyframed the normal velocity at random. I have tried starting from scratch but am having the same issue.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann here is a drive link to the rendered version with two identical particle systems, two emitters layered on top of each other, one with a slight z rotation. Each particle system has 5000 particles. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IiyJCPm9sD7E8J-BrtSjFxoVdLnMiXNJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You tried baking but the particles don't show up... well, this information together with the number of particles you changed is not really anyway sufficient to determine what the problem is. Also the video just looks like either the particles are not baked or any of the other dozens and dozens of settings are incorrect. I would suggest you upload your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question.